# Python: Can I create a dummy based on search conditions in one column with text series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp, lemmatization

I was wondering how I could create a dummy variable for the following condition: column 'lemmatised' contains at least two words from 'innovation_words'. Innovation_words is a list I defined myself:

```
innovation_words = ['community', 'local', 'charity', 'event', 'partner',
                'volunteering', 'plastic', 'surplusfood']
```

The lemmatised column looks like this (I'm fine changing the type or formatting if needed):

[data to use for condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWdud.png)

So, if any observation includes for example *local* and *plastic*, I would like to have a dummy variable: 'innovation' = 1. Hope someone can help me with this. Some code I already tried:

```
conditions = [df_posts['lemmatised'].isin(innovation_words), 
          df_posts['lemmatised'].isin(innovation_words)]

dummy = [1,0]

df_posts['innovation'] = np.select(conditions, dummy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use from this code

```py
df['new']=df.lemmatised.map(lambda w: len([i for i in innovation_words if i in w])>1)
```

just rename the variables

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked out nicely! I added "1 if ... else 0" to make it a dummy with values 1 and 0 instead of a boolean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```py
df_posts['innovation'] = 0 
df_posts.loc[df_posts.lemmatised.isin(innovation_words), 'innovation'] = 1
```